# How to remove duplicates from list without reordering in java?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, linkedhashset

I am trying to remove duplicates from my List object of the type String using Set Interface but the problem i face is that it also reorders my list which is something i don't want. I want to preserver the order of the list and remove duplicates only ?

```
static List<String>  StopNames = new ArrayList<String>();

StopNames.add(sCurrentLine);

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(StopNames);


for (String string : set) {

 System.out.println("Printing Set "+string);

}
```

Comment: use LinkedHashSet instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just switch `HashSet` for `LinkedHashSet`, which preserves insertion order while removing duplicates.